# Unable to start debugging on the web server. The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: wcf, debugging, iis, visual-studio-2015

We are developing a SOAP-based WCF Service in Visual Studio:

[image]

[image]

The virtual directory did get created.  However, when I try to run the code in Visual Studio 2015 (F5) Debug mode, it give me the following error:

> Unable to start debugging on the web server.  The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

The aforementioned error started showing up when our company changed their Windows Domain name. How I can resolve the problem?

Here are the technologies used in our development environment:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
- Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01  Update 3
- Internet Information Services ( Version 8.5.9600.16384 )

Comment: restarted the server and error disappeared (in the following screenshot on the right side)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I needed to make a Fake Self-Signed Certificate, and associate it with the https 443 port of the Web site as the picture below shows:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

1- Select your site in IIS.
2- Go to top-right and click on bindings.
3- Select your application and click edit.
4- Select a SSL certificate, if it doesn't exist then you may need to create
it.

[image]

Comment: This is the answer.  I had updated a cert and for some reason it get disassociated in the bindings.

Comment: After I install Visual Studio 2019, my Visual Studio 2015 can't run, and I can run under IIS. After rebinding the certificate, VS 2015 works again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after windows update.

1. Go to settings then update & Security.
2. Click on check online for updates from Microsoft update -> It will start downloading the updates and will installing automatically.
3. once installation and downloading completed it will ask for restart then go for restart the system and then try.

Comment: this question was about creating fake self-certificates when you are developing an application, and then deploying it to a standalone IIS server.